# Debug view minimizes when JUnit tests have finished

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit, minimized

Since some weeks I have the curious behaviour of IntelliJ Idea that when a Junit test (or a whole class with several tests) has finished running the debug/run window that shows the test results minimizes. This forces me to open the window again. Since I am starting hundreds of those tests per day this way I am totally annoyed by this. My colleges do not have that issue.

Any idea what configuration causes this and how I can disable that feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might have selected this Intellij configuration setting:

Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Debugger > Hide debug window on process termination

[image]

Just untick that and the Debug window/pane will remain open after the process completes.